Date string to considered as date type of excel(exporting json data using javascript)
I have a json objects containing dynamic properties and want to export it to excel(using javascript) such that excel recognizes date string(2020-03-13) as date object.
When I am using xlsx to download excel, generated excel doesn't recognize date string as date type of excel.
How can I resolve this with using xlsx library or without any library in javascript.
I tried using xlsx, it didn't work and date was general type in excel.
And also tried to first create tsv string then export it as .xlsx using blob with mimetype of xlsx files.(but excel not able to open it)
2 main points to consider

I can't convert date string to date objects.(as there multiple keys possible and I don't know which key have date string)
There are chances that in one object date is (2002-10-13) without time and in another object date is (2002-10-15 13:10:10) with time. And neither should be added nor should be removed in excel.

Demo code for json tsv to excel
// Sample JSON data
    const jsonData = [
        { "name": "John Doe", "age": 28, "date": "2023-10-08" },
        { "name": "Jane Smith", "age": 32, "date": "2024-03-15" },
        { "name": "Alice Johnson", "age": 45, "date": "2024-01-20" }
    ];

    // Convert JSON to TSV
    function jsonToTsv(jsonData) {
        const headers = Object.keys(jsonData[0]).join("\t");  // Get headers from JSON keys
        const rows = jsonData.map(row => 
            Object.values(row).join("\t") // Join values with tabs
        ).join("\n");  // Join rows with newline

        return `${headers}\n${rows}`;
    }

    // Download the TSV as an Excel file
    function downloadAsExcel(tsvData, fileName) {
        // Create a Blob for the TSV data and specify the MIME type as Excel
        const blob = new Blob([tsvData], { type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' });

        // Create a URL for the Blob
        const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

        // Create a link element
        const link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = url;
        link.download = fileName; // File name for download

        // Append the link to the document and trigger click
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();

        // Remove the link element and revoke the object URL
        document.body.removeChild(link);
        URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    }

    // Button click event to download JSON as Excel
    document.getElementById('download-btn').addEventListener('click', function () {
        // Convert JSON to TSV format
        const tsvData = jsonToTsv(jsonData);

        // Convert TSV to Excel format and trigger download
        downloadAsExcel(tsvData, "data.xlsx");
    });

Demo code by using xlsx:
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>

   <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>Download Excel from JSON</title>

    <!-- Add xlsx script from CDN -->

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.18.5/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>`

</head>

<body>

    <button onclick="downloadExcel()">Download Excel</button>

    <script>`

        // Sample JSON Data

        const jsonData = [

            { "name": "John Doe", "age": "28", "birthdate": "2023-10-08" },

            { "name": "Jane Smith", "age": "32", "birthdate": "2024-03-15" }

        ];

        // Function to Convert JSON Data to Excel and Trigger Download`

        function downloadExcel() {

            // Create a new workbook and worksheet

            const wb = XLSX.utils.book_new();  // Create a new workbook

            const ws = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(jsonData);  // Convert JSON to worksheet

            // Append worksheet to workbook

            XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, 'Sheet1');

`            // Trigger a download of the Excel file`

            XLSX.writeFile(wb, 'data.xlsx');`

        }



</body>

</html>


see the EDIT section in my post, I guess it is almost what you want, which somewhat depends @rotabor's comment. Please upvote and accept it as an answer if you find it useful

Sorry @Haluk, that is not I want to do only. The main pain of the problem is not knowing date keys and format.

You do not have to know the keys housing dates in my edited version. At this point, I can only say: .... Have good luck

For various date formats, try to include other date formats in the regex statements.

"want to export it to excel such that excel recognizes date string(2020-03-13) as date object" - do you mean that you want to import a json file to Excel?
You can just use the built-in option to import json file to Power Query.
 [
        { "name": "John Doe", "age": 28, "date": "2023-10-08" },
        { "name": "Jane Smith", "age": 32, "date": "2024-03-15" },
        { "name": "Alice Johnson", "age": 45, "date": "2024-01-20" }
  ]

Go to Data, Get data, From file, From Json, navigate to the file and open it.  The file is opened in Power Query:

Convert it to table, expand columns and format the required column as dates:
let
    Source = Json.Document(File.Contents("C:\Users\Michal\OneDrive\Documents\test.json")),
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(Source, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Expanded Column1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Column1", {"name", "age", "date"}, {"Column1.name", "Column1.age", "Column1.date"}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Column1",{{"Column1.date", type date}})
in
    #"Changed Type"



I don't get it, what language you have used, I want to do it in javascript. I want to write code to download a excel file using js such that date column behave as date in excel(same as your last shared ss). Currently from my code when i export excel date is string(general type) in excel.

@JoJo - I think you should look at your original question and re-write it as it's very unclear what you want to do.  Starting from scratch might be a good idea.

Using your original JSon array (jsonData) with string type dates, I first updated the array by converting these strings by date objects and continued working with SheetJS to create the Excel file for downloading;
<html>
  <body>
    <button onclick="downloadExcel()">Download Excel</button>

    <script src="https://cdn.sheetjs.com/xlsx-latest/package/dist/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      function downloadExcel()  {
        const jsonData = [
            { "name": "John Doe", "age": 28, "date": "2023-10-08" },
            { "name": "Jane Smith", "age": 32, "date": "2024-03-15" },
            { "name": "Alice Johnson", "age": 45, "date": "2024-01-20" }
        ];

        /* Update the array by converting 'date strings' to 'date objects' */
        jsonData.forEach(function(x) {
            x.date = new Date(x.date);
        });

        /* flatten objects */
        const rows = jsonData.map(row => ({
          name: row.name,
          age: row.age,
          date: row.date
        }));

        /* generate worksheet and workbook */
        const worksheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(rows);
        const workbook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
        XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(workbook, worksheet, "Staff");

        /* fix headers */
        XLSX.utils.sheet_add_aoa(worksheet, [["Name", "Age", "Date"]], { origin: "A1"});

        /* column widths */
        var wscols = [
                {wch:12},
                {wch:8},
                {wch:15}
              ];

        worksheet['!cols'] = wscols;

        /* create an XLSX file and try to save to Company.xlsx */
        XLSX.writeFile(workbook, "Company.xlsx", { compression: true });
      };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>

.
The output is given below, where column C is housing actual dates, not strings (text).
.

.
EDIT:
If you don't know which key or keys are housing date strings, as @rotabor has stated in his below comment, you need to make iteration over keys and values of the JSon array and then replace the date strings which are found, with necessary date objects.
In the below example, jsonData have two keys namely dateStart and dateEnd housing date strings with or without time values. The script, takes care about the date strings found in the keys of the array as required and creates the necessary Excel file without referring to key names explicitly. The dates in the Excel file are true dates, not text/string.
The script and the output is given below;
<html>
  <body>
    <button onclick="downloadExcel()">Download Excel</button>

    <script src="https://cdn.sheetjs.com/xlsx-latest/package/dist/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      function containsDate(inputString){
        return /(\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2})/.test(inputString)
      }
      
      function downloadExcel()  {
        const jsonData = [
              { "name": "John Doe", "age": 28, "dateStart": "2023-10-08", "dateEnd": "2023-12-17"},
              { "name": "Jane Smith", "age": 32, "dateStart": "2024-03-15", "dateEnd": "2024-07-29 15:10:17" },
              { "name": "Alice Johnson", "age": 45, "dateStart": "2024-01-20","dateEnd": "2024-03-08 10:04:27" }
          ];

          for (var i=0; i<jsonData.length; i++){
            Object.keys(jsonData[i]).forEach(function(key) {
              if(containsDate(jsonData[i][key])){
                jsonData[i][key]= new Date((jsonData[i][key]).match(/\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}/) + 'T00:00:00');
              }})
            }
         
        /* generate worksheet and workbook */
        const worksheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(jsonData);
        const workbook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
        XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(workbook, worksheet, "Staff");

        /* create an XLSX file and try to save to Company.xlsx */
        XLSX.writeFile(workbook, "Company.xlsx", { compression: true });
      };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>

.


I can't convert date string to js date object as I don't know which key contains date string(keys are dynamic).

You need to test like IsDate over fields.

@JoJo; see the EDIT section in my post, I guess it is almost what you want, which somewhat depends @rotabor's comment.

Converting date strings without time in js object will add wrong time in excel for all those strings, I don't want that. I want time stamp should not be added or removed from dates.

I'm not sure why, adding time part with 11 seconds seems work. If it is 10 seconds or less then the date is less than a day.
This is only a possible workaround - the may be better solutions.
        const time = 'T00:00:11';

        const jsonData = [

            { "name": "John Doe", "age": "28", "birthdate": new Date('2023-10-08' + time) },

            { "name": "Jane Smith", "age": "32", "birthdate": new Date('2024-03-15' + time) }

        ];


you may want to create a function to form an ISO string with time part and then a Date object



I don't know which column will be of date type so I can't convert date string to object. And se when you converted date string in date object it added time(which is wrong too).

Where has time appeared from?

@JoJo, this is just exploring possible workarounds. Excel doesn't read timezone information. And I'm not sure how the dates are converted in the package - many have reported time is offset incorrectly. Please see my latest 'discovery' in the updated answer.

@rotabor, it is from nowhere ;) it is just to get the date parsed and passed on with the values specified. I haven't looked at the package code to figure out what the best approach is.

@JoJo, this workaround is based on "Cell types are deduced from the type of each value. For example, a Date object will generate a Date cell, while a string will generate a Text cell." You may have to parse the column data to see which ones needs conversion.

Excel recognizes the data type when you enter it manually. In the programmatic way, the sheet content is highly dependent on the method json_to_sheet. If it writes a date as the text, Excel displays a text.
In this case, the best way to get the result is to use the DATEVALUE function in Excel.

Or you can use the custom 'json_to_sheet' method, or use another library to work with Excel files.

Excel primitive data types and formats:

A2 is intentionally entered as text (starting from the single quote mark). C-E content formulas with the function from the header. F refers to A, all cells with the General format.
So, there are 3 data types in Excel: 1) text; 2) number (double-precision floating point); 3) boolean.

Isn't there any way to it programmatically.

Yes, as per the last sentence.

No json_to_sheet didn't work for me, I can't use another liberary. And my nick is joh joh.

The only way is to change the library. Or don't use the json_to_sheet method but parse json record by record, field by field.

That is last option I think now. But still library is not giving correct dates too. If my date is not having any time, it will add it by own. And as I don't know the format of dates it looks more painful.

I told you, change the library.

But I am not allowed to change the library. Still it would great if you suggest better library.

Sorry, Java is not my area of expertise.

My problem was about javascript.

I understand it, but it doesn't matter. I can suggest you to read the documentation of
js-xlsx. May be, there are options there, or other possibilities to enforce 'json_to_sheet' change its behavior, or to customize it. May be, it will be helpful to recreate your question to focus on js-xlsx and this particular problem (it writes a text instead of the date).

Actually, there is no reason for 'json_to_sheet' to treat '"date": "2023-10-08"' as a date without special instructions. Other answers propose some ways to do it.

Thanks @rotabor, One more thing i want to ask is could you please tell me when i try to format date column(having date string) as date and try to apply date formats it is not working using format cell functionality of excel.
You can use https://onecompiler.com/html or any site to run html code to run my code(headed as - Demo code by using xlsx) to download xlsx(which is having this problem).

It's easy. Cell formatting works for the relevant data type only. If cell's content is text, date/time formatting doesn't work. You can check it in Excel interactively.
